# Checking a radio button in Protractor + AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing

I have a radio button on my html page and I'd like to test the value of the current selected option

```
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="enabled" checked/>
            <label for="radio1">Yes</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="disabled" />
            <label for="radio1">No</label>
        </div>
        <br />
```

I'm using this code on the page object I use to test

```
var radio = $("input[type='radio'][name='radio1']:checked").val();
```

Unfortunately I get

> val() is undefined

How can I return "enabled" or "disabled" based on the current status of the radio button?

Comment: Same result unfortunately

Comment: @Maximus `val()` is a jQuery function, he's using Protractor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`val()` is a jQuery function which you do not inherently have access to unless you setup Protractor that way.  Use `getAttribute('value')` instead, which returns a promise - see the [getAttribute() reference](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getAttribute)

So if you are using it in an assertion, you can let `expect` resolve the promise itself:

```
var radio = $("input[type='radio']:checked")
expect(radio.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('enabled');
```

Or if you want to access the value and use it elsewhere, resolve the promise yourself:

```
radio.getAttribute('value').then(function (val) {
    if(val === 'enabled') {
        // code
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'enabled' the value = 1

// using TS

```
static myElement = element
    .all(by.css('input[type="radio"]:checked'))
    .get(0);

expect(this.myElement.getAttribute('value')).toEqual(
      '1'
    );
```